# ldd can't find one library, but links to the other ones in same directory

Tags: software-installation, compiling, libraries, shared-library, ld

I'm trying to deploy my application. I created a deb package. If I install it on the same machine that I built it, everything works. When I try to use a deb package generated by my CI setup on gitlab, I encounter problems.

After installing, here's the error:

```
$ NCATests
NCATests: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is surprising, because I installed a conf file (`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nca.conf`) with a path `/usr/lib/nca` and ran a post-install ldconfig. To make sure that this worked I ran:

```
$ ldconfig -v
(snip)
/usr/lib/nca:
        libpcre2-16.so.0 -> libpcre2-16.so.0.7.1
        libicuuc.so.63 -> libicuuc.so.63.1
        libicui18n.so.63 -> libicui18n.so.63.1
        libicudata.so.63 -> libicudata.so.63.1
        libdouble-conversion.so.1 -> libdouble-conversion.so.1.0
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 -> libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.3
        libQt5Test.so.5 -> libQt5Test.so.5.11.3
        libQt5Gui.so.5 -> libQt5Gui.so.5.11.3
        libQt5DBus.so.5 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.11.3
        libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
        libNCACore.so.1 -> libNCACore.so.1.3.8
(snip)
```

And yet:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/NCATests
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc1081000)
        libNCACore.so.1 => /usr/lib/nca/libNCACore.so.1 (0x00007f049a368000)
        libQt5Test.so.5 => /usr/lib/nca/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x00007f049a310000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f049a0f0000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0499d60000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f04999c0000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0499790000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0499390000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f049a600000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
        libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

The library is there:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/nca | grep 5Core
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Mar 15 08:20 libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Mar 15 08:20 libQt5Core.so.5.11 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5200168 Mar 15 08:20 libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
```

Both files are 64 bit:

```
$ file /usr/bin/NCATests
/usr/bin/NCATests: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=8adef8969237a756f7d2743121f87791c8ceafc2, not stripped


$ file /usr/lib/nca/libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
/usr/lib/nca/libQt5Core.so.5.11.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b126d6e6aafc3d2d6e2b7904786b22e7e84e252e, for GNU/Linux 3.17.0, stripped
```

Ubuntu version 18.04. What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @tremby I'm sorry to say I didn't. I gave up on creating the deb package and my environment is long gone.

Comment: in my case, embarrassingly, it turned out I was making the same typo over and over again! libgdm vs libgbm

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install libqt5core5a
```

There is your missing libary

Comment: I already have bundled libraries in the deb package. Besides, version in the repositories does not match the version used for building the application.

Comment: Sorry, lost focus. `ldconfig -p | grep libQt5Core` please.

Comment: `libQt5Core.so.5 (libc6, x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.17.0) => /usr/lib/nca/libQt5Core.so.5`